# Jinja template groupby sorting issue

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, jinja2

In this code block, I have grouped by headings. But I want to sort the titles in array index order. Not alphabetically.

```
{% set list = widget.attributes.faq_item %}

{% for title_group in list|groupby('value.main_title') %}
  <h2 class="account-sss__title">{{title_group.grouper}}</h2>

  {% for item in title_group.list %}

    <a href="#" class="account-sss__list--link js-link">
        {{item.value.question}}
    </a>
    <div class="account-sss__content js-account-sss__content">
        {{item.value.answer}}
    </div>

  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you share the view, normally it is better to do this processing in the view, not the template.

Comment: i solved the problem. i share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
{% set list = widget.attributes.faq_item %}
{% set Arr_titles = [] %} 

{% for event in list %} 
  {% if event.value.main_title not in Arr_titles %}
   {% do Arr_titles.append(event.value.main_title) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for index in Arr_titles %}
  <h2 class="account-sss__title">{{index}}</h2>
  {% for item in list %} 
    {% if index == item.value.main_title %}
    <a href="#" class="account-sss__list--link js-link">
      {{item.value.question}}
    </a>
    <div class="account-sss__content js-account-sss__content">
      {{item.value.answer}}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```